# css list-style-image is not on (vertical) center

Tags: html, css, html-lists, vertical-alignment

I have this simple ul li script with list-style-image.

The problem is that the image is not  (vertical) center.

vertical-align is not helpful here.

Any idea ?

http://jsfiddle.net/nDX6g/

```
ul {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    color: #3C4355;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

li {
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #3C4355;
    line-height: 20px;
    list-style-image: url('http://forum.bizportal.co.il/NewSite/emoticons/smiley9.gif');
}




<ul>
    <li>Text 1</li>
    <li>Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: check the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454199/vertical-align-list-with-list-style-image

Comment: Using a background, margin, padding etc will help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708833/adjust-list-style-image-position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use background image to adjust background position properly:

```
li {
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #3C4355;
    line-height: 20px;
    background: url('http://forum.bizportal.co.il/NewSite/emoticons/smiley9.gif') 0 0 no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/nDX6g/2/

Answer (score 2):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nDX6g/3/

```
li {
   list-style: none;
}

li:before {
   content: url(...);
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin-right: .5em;
}
```

---

if your items may span on two (or more) lines, then try this other fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nDX6g/4/

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nDX6g/1/)**</kbd>

#### CSS

```
ul {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    color: #3C4355;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

li {
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #3C4355;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 25px;
    list-style: none;
    background: url('http://forum.bizportal.co.il/NewSite/emoticons/smiley9.gif') no-repeat left top;
}
```

#### Result

[image]