# Vertically centring bullet images

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I, like many other people, am trying to centre some custom bullets vertically. I've looked at a lot of other questions on SO but I can't find exactly the solution I'm looking for. I don't like the solutions using CSS `background: url("...")`. Examples of the solution I don't want:

[Vertical Align - List with "list-style-image"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454199/vertical-align-list-with-list-style-image)

[Adjust list style image position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708833/adjust-list-style-image-position)

Here is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
  li {
    position: relative;
    list-style-image: url("/images/bullet.png");
  }
  li>span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
</style>

<ul>
  <li><span>List item 1</span></li>
  <li><span>List item 2</span></li>
</ul>
```

It works pretty well, automatically adjusting to the size of the text but I have two issues with it:

1. I have to use a `<span>` inside each `<li>`
2. I have to hard-code the offset by half of the image height (my example image is 48px high so I've used `top: 24px;`)

I have two questions:

- Can this be done without knowing the image height?
- Is it possible to achieve the same effect without an inner element in each `<li>`, just text?

Remember, I've already seen the `background: url("...")` solution and I don't like it.

Comment: background is still a good method and much easier to handle. compatibility is high .... http://jsfiddle.net/TXeV6/  span + inline-block + vertical-align is fine too http://jsfiddle.net/TXeV6/1/

Comment: It's not a matter of whether you *like* some solutions or not, it's a matter of which one works best & most cross-browser. In that regard, your solution will fail on IE8 (5% usage world-wide) & Opera Mini (3% usage worldwide)(current) because they don't support [`transform`](http://beta.caniuse.com/#search=transform). While `list-style-image` &   `background-image` work for all browsers. The proposed `:before` solution is also a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add your custom bullet in a **li:before** styling instead of adding a span to every LI

Though if you want the full image to show up, you will need to know the height of the image.