# Vertical alignment of list-style-image with css

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm using an image as the bullet in **html** lists. However, I can not get the proper vertical alignment. I think this image explains very well the problem:

[image: sample]

What I would like is to have the black square centred with respect to the text. How could I get such behaviour?

I have tried `vertical-align: middle;` but it does not work. This is the **css** code creating this figure (note that I used a black square and a red border that allow to emphasise the problem):

```
#content ul{ 
  background: inherit;
  list-style-image:url('item-pin2.png');
  list-style-position: inside;
  margin-top:0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: DimGray;
}

#content li{ 
  background: inherit;
  margin:0.0em;
  padding: 0.0em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa3He.png)

Comment: Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454199/vertical-align-list-with-list-style-image and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427199/list-vertical-align-text-middle-with-list-style-image

Comment: OK, indeed my problem was solved in the other answers. Should I delete the question?